# Javascript for Facebook Like

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to add a facebook like button. I am using the standard XFBML code generated from developers.facebook.com. However, here's the problem: Say my use case is that mail will be sent to customers which will have a link to like my site. Now since you cannot include javascript in emails I have to redirect the user to an intermediate page, which hosts the like button. When the user clicks it he will be either asked to login or will be asked to like it.

I am looking for a way to automatically click the like button when the user clicks on the link from his email. So basically auto-liking the page when he clicks from his email, so that he does not have to click twice - (once on the email link and once on the like button on the intermediate page).The code that I am using is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>

function f1(d, s, id) {
  alert('Function Called');
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=171216266453";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="f1(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')">

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.google.com/" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I really hope this isn't possible!

Comment: I really really hope that this isn't possible either!!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK You cannon automatically click on Like Button on page visit. But you may consider an option of usage `iframe` version of like button.

Be warned that most online email providers will block it by default and may or may not allow to enable it optionally.

As for JavaScript solution it will be probably stripped out (or user will be **warned** in bad way) by most email providers and email clients.

Comment: I am aware that Javascript and also Iframe gets stripped off from most email clients.The email will have a button saying like on facebook and when the user clicks that button he will be redirected to a page that will host the like button . All I want is that the user does not have to click the like button again on that page. If there is a way to do it automatically, for the user it will be just one click on the button of the email . That's all. I am not trying to create some virus or script for auto-liking. I hope this makes the use case clearer. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't possible and even if it was possible it is for sure will violate [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

Answer (score 0):

Auto liking is not possible for like button. Embedding iframe also will be stripped off due to security reasons.